# Making PHP discard inline content before open tag on CLI

Tags: php, batch-file, command-line-interface, output-buffering

So. I have a batch file. In that batch file is PHP code. The "only" problem I have is that the "preamble" is printed when PHP is executed. "@rem Standby..."

Example batch file:

```
@rem Standby... <?php ob_start(); ?>
@echo off
echo Now in %comspec%
echo I am on %OS% with %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% CPUs    
echo Now handing off to PHP...
php.exe -f "%~f0" -- %*
goto :eof
<?php ob_clean(); ob_end_flush(); 
print "Now in PHP ".PHP_VERSION.PHP_EOL;
print "All done!";
```

Which outputs something like:

> ```
> Now in C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
> I am on Windows_NT with 4 CPUs
> Now handing off to PHP...
> @rem Standby... Now in PHP 7.1.0
> All done!
> ```

I know this is because of the nature of PHP's parser which considers anything outside of tags inline content which should be displayed. This script may be used in an environment where I can't depend on PHP's configuration.

How can I make PHP discard that inline content? (without editing the configuration)

PHP 7.1 on Win10

Comment: For what it's worth, a justification for this insanity is attempted here: [Batch wrapping PHP scripts](https://nxsys.assembla.com/spaces/onx/wiki/Batch_wrapping_PHP_scripts)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure output buffering is turned on at the configuration level, then you won't need to call `ob_start()`. This is pretty simple to do universally via command line parameters. Example:

```
@echo off
echo Now in %comspec%
echo I am on %OS% with %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% CPUs    
echo Now handing off to PHP...
php.exe -d output_buffering=On -f "%~f0" -- %*
goto :eof
<?php ob_clean(); ob_end_flush(); 
print "Now in PHP ".PHP_VERSION.PHP_EOL;
print "All done!";
```

Yields:

> ```
> Now in C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
> I am on Windows_NT with 4 CPUs
> Now handing off to PHP...
> Now in PHP 7.0.4
> All done!
> ```

Comment: Hmm this suggestion it feels familiar some how... I'm curious as to your inspiration?